# How to fit my android application for any phone or tablet screen?

Tags: android, resize, screen-orientation

Each phone or a tablet, what should I do in order to design the appropriate interface?

Wrote the application running  the screen with WVGA 3.7in but ım changed the screen 2.7in QVGA the application overflow the screen  on the other hand ım changed the screen 5.1in WVGA  the application  remain a little on the screen.

What can I do to fit any phone or tablet screen?

Answer (score 0):

You should read this guide: http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html

Answer (score 0):

1. First use relative layout
2. Make graphics for every density (ldpi, mdpi, hdpi and xhdpi)
3. Try to 9-patch your graphics.
4. Refer [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html) for more details.

Answer (score 0):

Except the things in previous answers you can consider adding following code if you want to make your app fullscreen:

```
requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
```

Comment: You tell your application to take full screen while creating main activity.